# For NSCoding, which "Export Compliance Information" option I should select?

Tags: ios, encryption, app-store, standards-compliance

Upload new version of app on App store or for TestFlight. Will need to add "Missing Compliance" warning details.

My app uses [NSCoding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoding), Which option I need to select from Apple "Export Compliance Information" for question "What type of encryption algorithms does your app implement?"
[image]

Comment: NSCoding is nothing to do with encryption.